# Python scapy sprintf syntax

Tags: python, scapy, ethernet, arp

```
ans,uans=srp(Ether(...)/ARP(pdst="x.x.x.x"),...)
for snd,rcv in ans:
  return rcv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")
```

Let's say I find the mac address of an IP using the above method. What does r in sprintf() mean and what is returned here? This may be a silly question but I'm not able to find an answer and I'm new to python. That's why I posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The r prefix has nothing to do with scapy.  r means raw string.  This means that backslashes in the string are treated as literal characters.  See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-bytesprefix).

For instance:

```py
>>> print(r'\n')
\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `sprintf` documentation using either `help(Packet.sprintf)` or using the online documentation: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html#scapy.packet.Packet.sprintf

`sprintf` is a function to format a packet's data in a human readable form.